# Android webview blank - Android 28 SDK

Tags: android, android-webview

Recently I updated the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` from **27** to **28** in my app. I'm using `Webview` in one of my screens just to display the justified text.

Here is the **code**

```
 WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
 String text = "Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet.";
 String contentStr = String.valueOf(Html
                    .fromHtml("<![CDATA[<body style=\"text-align:justify;color:#80000000; \"><i><small>"
                            + text
                            + "</small></i></body>]]>"));
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, contentStr, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

**Output When SDK version is 27**
[image: Output When SDK is 27]

When I update the SDK to 28 then it shows nothing.
**Output when SDK is 28**
[image: Output When SDK is 28]

I have tried with `webView.loadData(contentStr, "text/html", "utf-8");` But no result.
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue when I updated the SDK from 28 to 29.
header was loaded but body was empty

Comment: Is there any solution? I have the same problem after updated targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: Same issue here, switching from targetSdkVersion 27 to 28 (which is mandatory since yesterday btw !) despite using `wewview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW)` . No solutions have been found ?

Answer (score 0):

Ran your sample code in AS and everything seems to work.

[image]

Gradle:

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "stackoverflow.tomerpacific.com.so"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

Comment: please try to run it on Android 7.0 or above

Comment: @DeepakGoyal - The emulated device is a Pixel with API level 25, which is Nougat (Android 7.0)

Comment: I can share with you my source code so that you can take a look.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal - Upload pictures or code snippets of it

Comment: here is the link to source code https://github.com/deepak786/WebViewTesting

Comment: @DeepakGoyal - Have you tried creating a new project with Constraint Layout? I'm not seeing any difference between your code and mine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is already solved in this newer post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58182876/4927076)

Base64 encoding to string correctly works with newer Android SDK versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
            String text = "Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet.";
        String contentStr = "";
        int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (sdk < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            contentStr = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<body style=\"text-align:justify;color:#80000000; \"><i><small>"
                    + text
                    + "</small></i></body>]]>"));
        }
        else {
            contentStr = String.valueOf("<![CDATA[<body style=\"text-align:justify;color:#80000000; \"><i><small>"
                    + text
                    + "</small></i></body>]]>");
        }



        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, contentStr, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

In Android API 24 or more use it without Html.fromHtml() this function was Deprecated in API level 24