# Webview's loadData() is not working in android 10.0 (Q)

Tags: android, android-webview, android-10.0

Here i am trying to load Html code as string in webview's `loadData()` .Nothing is happen over this mehtod but same method is working like charm in below sdk 29.

```
webview.loadData(html_code,"text/html",null);
```

Note : Here i am not performing any encoding or decoding operation on string.I am simply passing it as string to above method.

Comment: any error log??

Comment: @amin nothing in log

Comment: solved after performing base-64 encoding to string.

Comment: you referred it from  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
So you must have accepted below answer

Comment: @amin before posting this question i already referred that docs.The issue is that the without encryption same code is working fine in below sdk 29. and to accept your answer 'setJavaScriptEnabled(true)'  is not related to my quetion.

Comment: i see a problem in your code

Answer (score 15):

Use this code, it will work.

```
String newhtml_code = Base64.encodeToString(html_code.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
        testWebView.loadData(newhtml_code,"text/html", "base64");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try calling

```
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(html_code.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

before

```
webview.loadData(encodedHtml , "text/html", "base64");
```

like below

```
    String html_code= "<html><body>Your Actualtext.</body></html>";
    String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(html_code.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadData(encodedHtml , "text/html", "base64");
```

for more details refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) link

Comment: Thanks amin. This solution worked for me on all devices, I was facing the problem when I migrated the code to android 10(target sdk-29) , web view was loading blank page. after this solution everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Now it is working after performing base-64 encoding to string `html_code`.

[Issue resolved by passing html_code string as per given instruction in docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

manifest file in

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

and

```
 WebSettings settings = wb_webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
String html_code = "html code";
wb_webview.loadData(Base64.encodeToString(html_code.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING) , "text/html", "base64");
```

Answer (score 3):

I came up with another solution by using [loadDataWithBaseURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

e.g.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", null, null)
```

It should use less CPU and memory resource as no need Base64 calculation and storing.

Answer (score 1):

I facing the same issue and fix it by using loadDataWithBaseURL() instead loadData() method

```
mWebView.loadData(mHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

solution:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,mHtml,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```